# Using Unicorn on Rails 4.0 deploying to Heroku 504 error at "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, unicorn

I'm trying to deploy my app to heroku but getting a 504 error, and an app page (vipp.heroku.com) that says "Application Error". My rails console reads as follows:

`config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:`

- development - set it to false
- test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
- production - set it to true

/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:191:in `normalize_conditions!': You should not use the`match`method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. (RuntimeError)
If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add`via: [:get, :post]`option.
If you want to expose your action to GET, use`get`in the router:
  Instead of: match "controller#action"
  Do: get "controller#action"
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:67:in`initialize'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1438:in `new'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1438:in`add_route'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1417:in `decomposed_match'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1398:in`block in match'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1389:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1389:in`match'
    from /app/config/routes.rb:16:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:316:in`instance_exec'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:316:in `eval_block'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:294:in`draw'
    from /app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in`load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in`load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in`block in load_paths'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in`load_paths'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:102:in`reload_routes!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.2.0/lib/devise/rails.rb:14:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in`call'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in`block in run_load_hooks'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in`run_load_hooks'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:55:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`instance_exec'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in`block in run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in`block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in`block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in`each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`run_initializers'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in`method_missing'
    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in`require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in`load_dependency'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in`require_environment!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:63:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in`require'
    from script/rails:6:in `'.

2015-01-29T18:44:55.600313+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vipp.herokuapp.com request_id=b473ecd3-a78f-473e-a1b7-926adad9ebb6 fwd="35.2.143.28" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your environment config files (`development.rb`, `production.rb` & `test.rb`) might be corrupt.
If you'd post those we could see what the exact issue is, in the meanwhile - here's an example of valid configurations for `config.eager_load`:

## production.rb

```
config.eager_load = true
```

## development.rb

```
config.eager_load = false
```

## test.rb

```
config.eager_load = false
```